# XMLHttpRequest Dosen't complete

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, readystate

I'm calling a PHP file with XMLHttpRequest, but now the call doesn't complete and I 
have no idea why. The `req.readyState` isn't 4, and I don't know why because the PHP file is okay and does exactly what supposed to (just echo a string).

Can anyone see what I can not see?

```
function processAjax(id, option) {
    if (option == "lpath") url = "<?php echo $mosConfig_live_site;?>/administrator/components/com_joomlaquiz/getinfo.php?id=" + id;
    else url = "<?php echo $mosConfig_live_site;?>/administrator/components/com_joomlaquiz/getinfo.php?cat=" + id;

    //create AJAX request
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Non-IE browsers
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onreadystatechange = targetDiv();
        try {
            req.open("GET", url, true);
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
        req.send(null);
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        if (req) {
            req.onreadystatechange = targetDiv();
            req.open("GET", url, true);
            req.send();
        }
    }
}
//this function handles the response from the ajax request

function targetDiv() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) { // Complete
        if (req.status == 200) { // OK response
            //all of the code below doesn't happen because its not the option
            if (option == "lpath") {
                var response = req.responseText.split('##');
                var articles = response[0].split(';');
                var quizes = response[1].split(';');

                document.getElementById("article_id").innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById("quiz_id").innerHTML = "";

                for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i = i + 2) {
                    if ((i + 1) <= articles.length) {
                        var option = new Option( /* Label */ articles[i + 1], /* Value */ articles[i]);
                        document.getElementById("article_id").options.add(option);
                    }
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < quizes.length; i = i + 2) {
                    if ((i + 1) <= quizes.length) {
                        var option = new Option( /* Label */ quizes[i + 1], /* Value */ quizes[i]);
                        document.getElementById("quiz_id").options.add(option);
                    }
                }

                delete req, articles, quizes;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("catdiv").innerHTML += req.responseText;
                document.getElementById("allchildren").value = req.responseText;
            }
        } else { //failed to get response
            alert("Problem: " + req.statusText);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("catdiv").innerHTML += "Y U NO COMPLETE?!";
}
```

Comment: Is `<?php echo $mosConfig_live_site;?>` part of the HTML source, or the PHP source? If it is part of the HTML source, your PHP is not being interpreted...

Comment: no it's not cross domain and mc10 i checked and the url outputs fine. this all source is the PHP source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
req.onreadystatechange = targetDiv();
```

should be

```
req.onreadystatechange = targetDiv;
```

The original code calls `targetDiv()` immediately after that line of code is run, which is probably not what you wanted to do. The fixed code calls the function correctly, after the Ajax request is received.

Comment: and if i want the targetDiv function to recive a parameter how do i do that? though it worked so thanks man!

Comment: You can't pass your own parameters to the function. `onreadystatechange` automatically passes the event object, which you can access with `function targetDiv (event) {` (now you can use `event` in your function), but other parameters cannot be passed.

Comment: now it dosen't return 200 status (ok) and clue why that might be?

Comment: What exact error code is it returning? See [list of HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) to match the code to the error message. It may be an issue with the page you are attempting to call.